# How to calculate the first variation of $\,y \rightarrow \int_{a}^{b} y(x)\,\mathrm dx\,$ with $\,V=C^{0}([a,b])$

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives, optimization, calculus-of-variations

So I was solving this problem and I wanted to know if I did everything right.

The problem is:

> I have to calculate the first variation of the functional
>
> $F:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\quad$ defined by
>
> $\displaystyle\;y\rightarrow\!\int_{a}^{b} \!y(x)\,\mathrm dx\;$ with $\;V=C^{0}([a,b])\,.$

So the formula I used is this: $\;\delta F[y]=\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}\cdot v$

First, we need to calculate the functional derivative $\partial F/\partial y$

$\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}&=\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{(F[y+\varepsilon v]-F[y])}{\varepsilon}\\
&=\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\int_{a}^{b}[y(x)+\varepsilon v(x)]\,\mathrm dx-\int_{a}^{b}y(x)\,\mathrm dx}{\varepsilon}\\
&=\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\int_{a}^{b}\varepsilon v(x)\,\mathrm dx}{\varepsilon}=\int_{a}^{b}v(x)\,\mathrm dx\,.
\end{align}$

So at the end, with $\;\delta F[y]=\partial F/\partial y\cdot v\,,\,$ I have :

$\displaystyle\delta F[y] =\int_{a}^{b}v(x)\,\mathrm dx\cdot v$

Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: That's correct.